# Is there anyway to Automate Azure MySql Import/Export

Tags: mysql, azure, powershell, azure-mysql-database

I am trying to Automate Import/Export process of Azure MySQL DB. Unlike Azure SQL DB I don't find the Azure PowerShell command or through Azure portal to perform Import/Export of Database. I want to have a script which can automate import/Export process of Azure MySQL DB.  I have referred Azure official doc and they are using other tool like MySQL workbench, which will not give the direct solution like Azure SQL DB. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

There is no Powershell command for Azure MySQL DB import/export. While [MySQL Workbench](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/mysql/concepts-migrate-import-export) is one way, but since you are looking for automation, you can consider [dump and restore using mysqldump cmd tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/mysql/concepts-migrate-dump-restore#dump-and-restore-using-mysqldump-utility) (can be found [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html)).